# Extending ast.AST

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a Python tool that walks an AST to extract some data.
To improve its usability, I want to extend the `ast.AST` class, so every node that is based on it has the same ability, for example getting the parent node, the children, the siblings, etc.

On Python 3.9+, I'm able to attach additional attributes, methods and cached properties to `ast.AST` directly:

```
def _attach_to(cls, name=None):
    def decorator(func):
        func_name = name or func.__name__
        cached = cached_property(func)
        setattr(cls, func_name, cached)
        # see https://bugs.python.org/issue38524
        cached.__set_name__(cls, func_name)  # noqa: WPS609
        return func
    return decorator
```

But on Python 3.8, which I'm willing to support, I cannot attach additional things to `ast.AST` which is a builtin:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type '_ast.AST'
```

So I explored different things:

- patching `ast.AST` with a class of mine, using patch functions such as `unittest.mock.patch`: it does not seem to affect the child classes which already inherited from the original `ast.AST`
- patching `ast.AST.__mro__`: `__mro__` is readonly
- patching `ast.AST.__bases__`: can't set attributes of built-in
- iterating on subclasses and changing `ast.AST` to my own `ExtendedAST` (that inherits from `ast.AST`) in their `__bases__`: complains about object layout differing

Is there a way to dynamically add attributes/methods/properties to built-in classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found something that works: I declare an `ExtendedAST` class, but instead of making it a subclass of `ast.AST`, I leave it as a "mixin" and append it to the `__bases__` of all the different nodes' classes:

```
for name, member in inspect.getmembers(ast):
    if name != "AST" and inspect.isclass(member):
        if ast.AST in member.__bases__:
            new_bases = list(member.__bases__)
            new_bases.append(ExtendedAST)
            member.__bases__ = tuple(new_bases)
```